# Error al subir archivos pesados con ajax y php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, servidor

hoy vengo con otro inconveniente, estoy tratando de subir a mi servidor archivos de mas de 100mb, pero al darle subir y empieza a procesar la subida del archivo me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Al igual que este otro error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya configuré el **php.ini** para que me permitiera subir archivos pesados, pero aún así no me permite subirlos y no encuentro mucha información sobre este error, algunos dicen que podría ser el add block, el cual desactive y aún así nada, probé en dos navegadores más (En chrome y edge. El que uso es opera gx) y aún así dan el mismo problema.

Este es mi código .js

```
$(document).ready(() => {

$('.upload_file').on('submit',  upload);
function upload(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let form     = $(this),
    wrapper      = $('.barra'),
    wrapper_f    = $('.wrapper_files'),
    progress_bar = $('.progress_bar'),
    data         = new FormData(form.get(0));

    //Inicializando la barra de progreso
    progress_bar.removeClass('barra_verde barra_roja').addClass('text-info');
    progress_bar.css('width', '0%');
    progress_bar.html('Preparando...');
    wrapper.fadeIn();

    return $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            let xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    let percentComplete = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);

                    //mostrar el progreso
                    progress_bar.css('width', percentComplete+'%');
                    progress_bar.html(percentComplete+'%');
                }
            }, false);

            return xhr;
        },
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : "./action/backup.php",
        dataType    : 'json',
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        cache       : false,
        data        : data,
        beforeSend : () => {
            $('button', form).attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }).done(res => {
        if(res.status === 200) {
            progress_bar.removeClass('text-info').addClass('barra_verde');
            progress_bar.html('¡Listo!');
            form.trigger('reset'); //Reinicia el formulario

            // Agregamos un botón de descarga del archivo
            wrapper_f.append('<a class="NewDownload" href="'+res.data+'" download>Descargar recien subidos: '+res.data+'</a>');

            setTimeout(() =>{
                wrapper.fadeOut();
                progress_bar.removeClass('barra_verde barra_roja').addClass('text-info');
                progress_bar.css('width', '0%');
            }, 1500);
        }else{
                alert(res.msg);
                progress_bar.css('width', '100%');
                progress_bar.html(res.msg);
            }
    }).fail(err => {
        progress_bar.removeClass('barra_verde text-info').addClass('barra_roja');
        progress_bar.html('¡Hubo un error!');
        swal(JSON.stringify(err),{
            icon: "error"
            });
    }).always(() => {
        $('button', form).attr('disable', false);
    });
}
});
```

Los archivos livianos **si me permite** subir sin ningún inconveniente.
(EL JQUERY QUE VEN AHÍ ES DE UNA PLANTILLA, PERO AÚN ASÍ EN MI SERVIDOR LOCAL ME PERMITE SUBIR ESTOS ARCHIVOS PESADOS SIN NINGÚN INCONVENIENTE).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo leer de la documentación oficial de PHP [este articulo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php)

Comment: Hola, ya me había asegurado de eso, ya esta bien establecido los tamaños en el php.ini

Comment: Puede ser Apache tambien.  Hay este parametro en /etc/php/apache2/php.ini upload_max_filesize = 100M

Comment: Gracias por responder @Duston, eso cómo podría acceder en mi host? 
 Cree un documento con <?php phpinfo(); ?> Para ver toda la configuración, en la parte de **upload_max_filesize** Sale dos columnas una es **Local value** y otra es **Master Value**, estas estan así: `upload_max_filesize 2g 2M`

Comment: verifica también el valor de post_max_size en el php.ini por default creo trae 8M, eso me solucionó el problema

Comment: ¿Qué dice el log de php y la variable `$_FILES[‘tu archivo']['error’]`?

Comment: Gracias por responder @darcan, el valor de **post_max_size** está configurado así: `post_max_size = 4g`

Comment: @Sal en el log no sale nada referente a $_FILES